# После копирования файла БД в папку Documents приложение перестало видеть таблицы

Tags: java, android, база-данных, sqlite

Копирую файл БД из `Assets` в `Documents`.

Пути получаю так:

```
File docFolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
if (!docFolder.exists()) {
    docFolder.mkdirs();
}
dbFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), DB_NAME);
```

Копирую так:

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream input = fContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = dbFile.getAbsolutePath();
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    }
```

После копирования в `Documents` приложение перестало видеть таблицы в БД. Если скопировать файл БД в приватную папку через `Context` проблем нет, но меня этот вариант не устраивает (после удаления нужно чтобы БД сохранялась).

Как быть?

Работаю с Android 6.

Comment: Логи смотрели - ошибок нет? При открытии базы указываете полный путь к файлу или только имя?

Comment: Путь передаётся правильный. Если вытащить БД на комп, всё нормально открывается.

Comment: Если используете `SQLiteOpenHelper` - то у него свои тараканы, в этой статье показано как его обмануть с помощью кастомного контекста: https://medium.com/@mostasim/read-external-database-with-sqliteopenhelper-on-android-e87d66891f4e

Comment: @woesss, да именно `SQLiteOpenHelper` использую. Спасибо. Почитаю статью. Надеюсь поможет.

Comment: @woesss, огромное спасибо! Статья действительно помогла!